# GARCH parameter estimation and forecast in R with rugarch package

Tags: r

I have a problem with parameter estimation and forecast for a GARCH model.
I have a time series of volatilities, starting in 1996 and ending in 2009.
I tried to estimate the parameters with the `ugarchspec` and `ugarchfit` function:

```
garch1.1 <- ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)),mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0)),distribution="std")
garch1.1fit <- ugarchfit(spec=garch1.1,data=RV)
```

The results seemed to be okay, so I went on with the forecast.
I wanted to use the `ugarchforecast` or `ugarchroll` function. But when I tried to do it, I recognized that they work with the wrong date. For example, If I try to do a simple forecast like

```
forecast <- ugarchforecast(garch1.1fit,n.ahead=2)
```

I get the following results:

```
0-roll forecast [T0=1979-04-05 01:00:00]:
    Series     Sigma
T+1  5.373e-05 3.733e-05
T+2  5.373e-05 3.762e-05
```

So my problem is: **why does R say that T0=1979?** This cant be correct as my data starts in 1996 and ends in 2009.
When I had a look at the residuals from garch1.1fit, the date is also wrong. 
What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what object do you use as `RV`, but I assume it is a numeric vector. Package rugarch works better with `xts` objects supported by `xts` package.

Following code should do the job:

```
require(xts)

time <- #put here time vector from your data
RV.xts <- na.omit(xts(x = RV, order.by = time))
```

and then your code with changed object `RV` for new one `RV.xts`:

```
garch1.1 <- ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="sGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)),
                       mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0)),
                       distribution="std")
garch1.1fit <- ugarchfit(spec=garch1.1,data=RV.xts)
forecast <- ugarchforecast(garch1.1fit,n.ahead=2)
```

The code i provided does two things: first it makes an `xts` object using `time`. This object will tell your `ugarchfit()` function what is the time of this model. Second, it omits possible NA data, which function `ugarchfit()` do not handle.

Make sure if object `xts` connected dates correctly by checking:

```
head(RV.xts)
tail(RV.xts)
```

Comment: Thankk you so much for your help!!! I used as.POSIXct function for "time" and now everything works correctly!

Comment: could you also help me with my other issue? It is called "EWMA forecast with a rolling window in R"

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not specify date for your ugarch model. Note that R "Date" class is coded in the number of days from the day `1970-01-01`.

Following code may help to understand the concept:

```
as.Date("1970-01-01")
as.numeric(as.Date("1970-01-01"))

as.Date("1970-01-10")
as.numeric(as.Date("1970-01-10"))
```

As the date is not specified for ugarch model, your data seems to have the number of observations to fill the 1970-1979 years (probably weekends are excluded), and the prediction starts after that period.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And yes, the weekends are excluded in my data. Is this a bigger problem? Could you please tell me how I can resolve this problem? As I'm a beginner with R, it is quite hard for me to do all this stuff here.

Comment: I think weekends are minior problem if you start sime series. I provided possible solution in other post.